# How to select distinct query using symfony2 doctrine query builder?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, query-builder

I have this symfony code where it retrieves all the categories related to a blog section on my project:

```
$category = $catrep->createQueryBuilder('cc')
    ->Where('cc.contenttype = :type')
    ->setParameter('type', 'blogarticle')
    ->getQuery();

$categories = $category->getResult();
```

This works, but the query includes duplicates:

```
Test Content
Business
Test Content
```

I want to use the `DISTINCT` command in my query.  The only examples I have seen require me to write raw SQL. I want to avoid this as much as possible as I am trying to keep all of my code the same so they all use the QueryBuilder feature supplied by Symfony2/Doctrine.

I tried adding `distinct()` to my query like this:

```
$category = $catrep->createQueryBuilder('cc')
    ->Where('cc.contenttype = :type')
    ->setParameter('type', 'blogarticle')
    ->distinct('cc.categoryid')
    ->getQuery();

$categories = $category->getResult();
```

But it results in the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::distinct()

How do I tell symfony to select distinct?

Comment: You should be passing a boolean value to the distinct() function. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#_distinct

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you could write

```
select DISTINCT f from t;
```

as

```
select f from t group by f;
```

thing is, I am just currently myself getting into Doctrine, so I cannot give you a real answer. but you could as shown above, simulate a distinct with [group by](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/doctrine/orm/query/expr/groupby.html) and transform that into [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language:group-by,-having-clauses/en). if you want add further filtering then use `HAVING` after group by.

Comment: @mickburkejnr Until You add an ORDER clause. :(

Comment: @xyu I know, it's not ideal really is it? Why should we be lumbered with something like this? Why can't it just work?

Comment: @mickburkejnr Grouping happens before ordering in SQL.

Comment: This is only the correct answer if you are using a sql statement and not the Query Builder. This should not be marked as the answer the solution given by @skler is the correct.

Comment: (Old comment, I know...). @Tom T: Actually, this answer is valid. It is saying that instead of trying to use the *actual* `DISTINCT` keyword, simulate it by using `GROUP BY`, in QueryBuilder. He failed to give an example, however. Here's a simple one: `$q = $db->createQueryBuilder(); $q->select('f')->from('t', 't')->groupBy('f');`

Comment: This sholdn't be an answer for the question

Answer (score 192):

This works:

```
$category = $catrep->createQueryBuilder('cc')
        ->select('cc.categoryid')
        ->where('cc.contenttype = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', 'blogarticle')
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery();

$categories = $category->getResult();
```

### Edit for Symfony 3 & 4.

You should use `->groupBy('cc.categoryid')` instead of `->distinct()`

Comment: Why is that exactly? It looks like it behaves differently. Sometimes we want ->distinct(). When you want to "iterate" over a query with "->toIterable()" while having a join with a ...ToMany relation in the query, then the groupBy is not enough. It must be ->distinct() for the ->toIterable() to work

Comment: It's extremely bad practice to use 'group by' and it can throw an error "GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Answer (score 58):

If you use the "select()" statement, you can do this:

```
$category = $catrep->createQueryBuilder('cc')
    ->select('DISTINCT cc.contenttype')
    ->Where('cc.contenttype = :type')
    ->setParameter('type', 'blogarticle')
    ->getQuery();

$categories = $category->getResult();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just open your repository file and add this new function, then call it inside your controller:

```
 public function distinctCategories(){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('cc')
        ->where('cc.contenttype = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', 'blogarticle')
        ->groupBy('cc.blogarticle')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

Then within your controller:

```
public function index(YourRepository $repo)
{
    $distinctCategories = $repo->distinctCategories();


    return $this->render('your_twig_file.html.twig', [
        'distinctCategories' => $distinctCategories
    ]);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by "none worked"? What happens instead? Why should that be a problem of Symfony, while the query builder is part of Doctrine?

Comment: @NicoHaase, because creating a new Symfony project via composer will install the newest version of Twig and Doctrine, that's why I mentioned that my solution is tested with Symfony5 and whatever Doctrine version comes with it. Hope it is more clear now.