# How to use "DISTINCT ON (field)" in Doctrine 2?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I know how to use "DISTINCT" in Doctrine 2, but I really need to use "DISTINCT ON (field)" and I don't know how to do this with the QueryBuilder.

My SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (currency) currency, amount FROM payments ORDER BY currency
```

And this query works perfect, but I can't use it with the QueryBuilder. Maybe I could write this query on some other way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "DISTINCT ON" syntax.  Is that similar to GROUP BY?

Comment: @daniel: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: You can read this post : 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246939/zf2-doctrine-2-objectselect-with-distinct-on-field

Comment: I think using query builder the answer is here

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188219/how-to-select-distinct-query-using-symfony2-doctrine-query-builder

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the `SELECT DISTINCT ON (..)` construct that PostgreSQL supports is outside the Object Relational Model (ORM) that is central to Doctrine. Or, perhaps put another way, because `SELECT DISTINCT ON (..)` is rare in SQL implementations Doctrine haven't coded for it.

Regardless of the actual logic for it not working, I would suggest you try Doctrine's "[Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)". You need to map the results of your query to the ORM.

> With `NativeQuery` you can execute native SELECT SQL statements and map
>   the results to Doctrine entities or any other result format supported
>   by Doctrine.
>
> In order to make this mapping possible, you need to describe to
>   Doctrine what columns in the result map to which entity property. This
>   description is represented by a `ResultSetMapping` object.
>
> With this feature you can map arbitrary SQL code to objects, such as
>   highly vendor-optimized SQL or stored-procedures.

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (..)` falls into **vendor-optimized SQL** I think, so using `NativeQuery` should allow you to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine QueryBuilder has some limitations. Even if I didn't check if it's was possible with query builder, I do not hesitate to use DQL when I do not know how to write the query with query builder.

Check theses examples at
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX BY` can be used in DQL, allowing first result rows indexed by the defined string/int field to be overwritten by following ones with the same index:

```
SELECT 
    p.currency, 
    p.amount 
FROM Namespace\To\Payments p INDEX BY p.currency 
ORDER BY p.currency ASC
```

[DQL - EBNF - INDEX BY](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#from-join-and-index-by)