# avoid duplication in many to many relationship - Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

noob alert;

I have `Post` and `Tag` Entities like this:

`Post.php`

```
 /**
 * Many posts can have many tags. This is the owning side.
 * @ORM\ManytoMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_tag")
 */
 protected $tags;
```

`Tag.php`

```
 /**
 * Many tags can belong to many different posts. This is the inverse side
 * @ORM\ManytoMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags")
 */
 protected $posts;
```

Now, I want to query all posts with their tags.

For that, I'm using queryBuilder in my Repository and successfully able to retrieve results.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('P')
        ->select('P.title, T.name')
        ->leftJoin('P.tags', 'T')
        ->where('P.id = 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

But as you can possibly imagine, this query fetches duplicates. So, if I had two tags for a post, there would be two similar posts inside the array.

`Output`

```
array(
  array(title=>'Post One', name=>'php'),
  array(title=>'Post One', name=>'python'),
)
```

Is there a doctrine way to turn these tags into an array collection and stuff this back into the final post array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select distinct query using symfony2 doctrine query builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188219/how-to-select-distinct-query-using-symfony2-doctrine-query-builder)

Comment: @malarzm thanks i'm gonna give it shot though i'm not sure if it's actually related

Comment: Sorry I might have jumped the gun with that flag. If DISTINCT is not working for entities try grouping by post's id.

Comment: can you maybe post an example, sorry not an experienced doctrine user..

Comment: @malarzm I'm not sure if it's even possible with doctrine. i'm gonna stick to raw sql for now. `GROUP_CONCAT` working fine for me in this matter. or perhaps there's something i might be missing nd will probably get in the future. thanks anyways